# push to observable variable in angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

How would I add an extra object to a collection which has been initially subscribed to an observable from the template. So I have a variable in my component which is an observable and then I do some http request and set the observable to this service request like so...

```
logs$: Observable<any>;

this.logs$ = this.service.getLogs(searchCriteria);
```

.. then in the template I am subscribing to this observable using async pipe.

```
<div *ngIf="logs$ | async as logs; else loading">
```

After this data is loaded there is some functionality to then add a new log and I want to then push this new log to the collection to display once it has been saved. Can I push a new value to this observable and reopen the subscription to it or do I need to manually subscribe to this in the component and have the collection there so then I can push to it in the component. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't need to re-subscribe to the observable if you push a new value into `logs$`

Comment: Is `this.service.getLogs` returing http call observable? If so, you are out of luck as http observables are terminated after execution (unles you use pipe share() into them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `this.service.getLogs` returing http call observable? If so, you are out of luck as http observables are terminated after execution (unles you use pipe share() into them).

If I were you, I would keep logs as separate collection. In such scenario I am free to modify that collection and it will be reflected by UI without any tricks.

What I would do

```
this.logs:Array<Logs>; //declaration
this.service.getLogs(searchCriteria).subscribe(result=>logs=result); // execution in onInit
```

and to add log on demand

```
this.logs.push(newLog);
```